# Ask How to display data from pivot tables in blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am confused. I want to display all loan data with a username to the table in the blade. This is my confusion :

This table I want to display in blade :

[This Table I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQsuZ.png)

This is the table that i use :

[This is the table that i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qap3E.png)

This My Model User  :

```
public function book(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class, 'loans')->withPivot(['loan_date','status'])->withTimeStamps();
}
```

This My Book Model :

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'loans')->withPivot(['loan_date','status'])->withTimeStamps();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get access to the pivot data from any model just call it like this:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->books->pivot->status}}
@endforeach
```